# use then() to make function run sequentially in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

i want to run loop function in sequence bus the function always gets async
is there any way to make it sync without using callback or any external library

file 1

```
var db = require('./promiseUnderStanding');

var fun = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        db.getFromDb(i, 0);
    }
}
fun();
```

file2

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
module.exports = {
 getFromDb : function (num1,num2) {
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        database: 'demo'
    });
    connection.connect();
    connection.query('SELECT '+num1+' + '+num2 +' AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        else {
            console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
        }
    })
    connection.end();
}

}
```

Comment: if it is async, then I think your `connection.end()` might be on the wrong place, shouldn't it be part of the calback then (otherwise your connection might be closed before the query is really executed?)

Comment: You can read about async-await in javascript. https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: You should use the modern JS concepts that follow ES6, like use `let` and `const` instead of `var` and `async-await` instead of callbacks. You can also use `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 2):

If function is async, this means it returns a Promise.

```
const myFunc = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        if(failed){
            reject(dataSendToCatch);
        }if(!failed){
            resolve(dataSendToThen);
        }
    })
};
```

This is almost the same as:

```
const myFunc = async function(){
    if(failed) throw new Error();
        return dataSendToThen;
};
```

After running your function, you can chain async or even sync functions:

```
myFunc()
.then(function(dataFromResolve){return otherFunc()})
.then(function(dataFromOtherFunc){/*...*/});
```

For continous handling, filtering, maping received data from async functions is good [rxjs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) library.

Comment: I know indentation is optional but this is so much harder to read, why not format the code blocks a bit?

Comment: Here you are ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to run an asynchronous promise synchronously.

However what you are looking for is `Promise.all()`. Additionally `connection.open` is also asynchronous, and  opening and closing connections to mysql rapidly is not efficient. You should open the connection before your loop, do the queries and then close it (not shown in my example).

Example

File 1:

```
var db = require('./promiseUnderStanding');

var fun = function () {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        promises.push[db.getFromDb(i, 0)];
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(values){
        console.log(values):
    })
}
fun();
```

File 2:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
module.exports = {
    getFromDb : function (num1,num2) {
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        database: 'demo'
    });
    var queryPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        connection.connect(function(err){
            connection.query('SELECT '+num1+' + '+num2 +' AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error)
                }
                else {
                    resolve(results)
            }
        });
    })})
    connection.end();
    return queryPromise;
    }
}
```

Comment: yep, promise.all would solve the issue. I dont think it`s a good idea to write synchronous code unnecessarily in node.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be about asynchronous functions so I'm considering the database logic as out of scope.

Use [async-await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

File 1:

```
const fun = async function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        await db.getFromDb(i, 0);
    }
}
fun().then(onFinish).catch(onError);
```

File 2:

```
module.exports.getFromDb = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // If success
        resolve(result);
        // If fail
        reject(error);
    });
}
```

- A function that returns a **Promise** is async.
- A Promise must either resolve or reject.
- Use await inside async function *A* when calling async function *B* to wait for *B*'s promise to resolve or reject
- If you use the **async** keyword to define a function, its return value will be wrapped inside an implicit Promise.