# how to pass a value from returned promise to the next function.

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

**how do I pass my user variable from my promise to my getworkspace function**

basically, my get user function currently finds a user from the given parameter and the promise is resolved since there's no error.

I then chain my getworkspace function to console.log this passed variable

```
function getworkspace(user) {
    // get all workspaces with passed id
    console.log('getting channels using id: ', user );
}

function getuser(id) {
    return new Promise (( resolve, reject) => {

    // found user details ...

    var user = { id: 'gh5g543', username: 'devcoffee', pass: '5hbfvh' };

    const error = false;

    if (!error) { resolve(); }
    else        { reject('error: somethings wrong')  }
  });
}

getuser( 'devcoffee' )
.then(getworkspace)
.catch( err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: `resolve(user)`

Comment: thanks. i'm now killing myself with how easy of a fix that is. first time trying promises

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use then() to make function run sequentially in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627714/use-then-to-make-function-run-sequentially-in-node)